# Si può usare "purché" per esprimere un desiderio?

Tags: word-usage, conjunctions

Nel romanzo *Bàrnabo delle montagne* di Dino Buzzati ho letto:

> «Bàrnabo si è accorto che Bertòn si è allontanato improvvisamente ma non osa rompere il silenzio per chiamarlo. Arrampicatosi per una obliqua cengia, Bertòn è voltato fuori, sulla parete che chiude il canalone. Dopo poco tutti lo vedono aggrappato a delle rocce verticali, sotto gli ultimi lastroni. *Purché* non succeda un altro disastro.»

Non ne sono sicura, ma la mia impressione è che il vocabolo "purché" sia usato in questo contesto per esprimere un desiderio (si desidera che non succeda un altro disastro). Potreste confermarmelo? Se è così, potreste farmi altri esempi di questo uso di "purché"?

Comment: Non trovo una fonte attendibile e quindi metto come commento la mia impressione: trovo che sia sì l'espressione di un desiderio, ma che formalmente si tratti di una proposizione condizionale in cui la principale è sottintesa: «(segua pure quel percorso/faccia pure di testa sua...) purché non succeda etc.»

Comment: @DaG: Forse l'esempio riportato dal [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/purche/), "*purché sia vero!*", è in certo modo simile a questo.

Answer (score 1):

Più che per esprimere un desiderio, a me sembra che 'purché' venga usato per scongiurare una disgrazia. Il significato mi sembra vicino ad affinché.  (Affinché non succeda un altro disastro).

[Purché](http://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Italiano/parola/P/purche.aspx?query=purch%C3%A9):

> - **A patto che, a condizione che** (si usa per introdurre una propos. condizionale con il v. al congiunt.):
>
>   - Purché se ne vada sono disposto ad accettare ogni sua pretesa;
>   - andrei volentieri a trovarlo purché mi accogliesse con simpatia.

Comment: Voglio dire il desiderio di che non succeda un altro disastro. A me sembra che gli esempi che hai citato facciano un uso diverso del vocabolo "purché".

Comment: Gli esempi sono riportati da un dizionario ( vedi il link). Concordo con te, mi sembra che sia usato col significato di 'affinché' ed esprima un augurio/desiderio che non succeda  un altra disgrazia.

Comment: Non ho presente questo uso ottativo di “affinché”. Dove lo hai trovato?